# Caesar Cipher bruteforce

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, brute-force, caesar-cipher

This is my class exercise we have to brute force the follow "hdvb wr euhdn" and find the key that works, but my code breaks it (I think correctly) but two different keys produce the same outcome. Is this normal or am I doing it wrong?

Key 2 and 11 work, and a few others that don't work still repeat the same characters. We just covered basic Caesar shift ciphers and I figured this approach was the best brute force . 
[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<String>

using std::string;
using std::endl;

void bruteForce(string x);

void bruteForce(string x)
{

    int key = 0;

    int length = (int)x.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        key++;
        std::cout << "The key is  " << key << endl;
        std::cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {

            if (x[j] == ' ')
            {
                x[j] = ' ';
                std::cout << x[j];
                j++;
            }
            x[j] = tolower(x[j]);
            x[j] -= 97;
            x[j] -= key;
            if (x[j] < 0)
            {
                x[j] += 26;

            }
            x[j] += 97;

            std::cout << x[j];
        }

        std:: cout << endl;

    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are modifying the string in place, which would mean each loop is getting different input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each loop is modifying the input as mentioned by Alexander O'Mara - refactor to separate the key change from the test.

Declare a function for the testing (separate to brute-force)

```
void Test(std::string x, int key);
```

Call it from bruteForce.

```
void bruteForce(string x)
{

    int key = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        key++;
        Test( x, key );
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
void Test(std::string x, int key)
{
    int length = (int)x.length();
    std::cout << "The key is  " << key << endl;
    std::cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        if (x[j] == ' ')
        {
            x[j] = ' ';
            std::cout << x[j];
        }
        else {
            x[j] = tolower(x[j]);
            x[j] -= 97;
            x[j] -= key;
            if (x[j] < 0)
            {
                x[j] += 26;

            }
            x[j] += 97;
        }
        std::cout << x[j];
    }

    std::cout << endl;



}
```

I slightly changed your skip for space, so that 2 spaces in a row, wouldn't confuse it.

The code works because each call to `Test` is a new copy of the pristine string.  Each successive key for a cesear cypher shifts by one character, so that should have alerted you to the re-use of the string.

Comment: Your declaration for `Test` is incorrect. It should be `void Test(std::string x, int key);`, but you have `void Test(std::string s, int key);`.

Comment: More inconsistent than incorrect - names are ignored in declaration

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following function to decrypt the Caesar cipher code

```
void decrypt(char arr[],int key){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++){
    if(arr[i]==' ')
        continue;
    for(j=0;j<key;j++){
        arr[i]--;
        if(arr[i]<97 && arr[i] > 90)
            arr[i] = 122;
        if(arr[i] < 65)
            arr[i] = 90;
    }

}}
```

To brute force, you can simply put the above function into a for loop which will iterate from 1 to 26 providing all the 26 possible keys to the decrypt function. Below is the example

```
int main(){
int i;
char arr[100],copy[100];
printf("Enter a string: ");
scanf ("%[^\n]s", arr);
strcpy(copy,arr);
for(i=1;i<=26;i++){
    encrypt(arr,i);
    printf("Bute Force key : %d ---> %s\n",i,arr);
    strcpy(arr,copy);
}}
```

Encrypt Function source : [C program to implement Caesar Cipher Algorithm](http://www.psychocodes.in/c-program-to-implement-caesar-cipher-algorithm.html)